# Mac -- Macports/Wine errors: NCurses library and Fontconfig

Tags: macos, macports, wine, fontconfig, ncurses

I've been trying to get Wine on my Mac to run some of my old PC games.
I used Macports to install it, but it didn't work right away. I followed [This](http://www.cultofmac.com/185565/how-to-run-almost-any-windows-game-on-your-mac-without-boot-camp-or-parallels-feature/2/)
 tutorial, and then looked around a bit on the web for solutions, but nothing worked.

When trying to run my exe, this is what happens:

> I entered
>
> ```
> wine ~/Desktop/Pokemon3D.exe
> ```
>
> and I get:
>
> ```
> Wine cannot find the ncurses library (libncurses.5.4.dylib).
> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
> ```
>
> (There's some more, but I'll post it at the end)

I'm not sure what's not working, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Please help!

## The code AFTER what is above

Pokemon:

> libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed
>   fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x1688848,0x32f3f8: stub
>   fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x1687f78,0x32f3f8: stub
>   fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x1690318,0x32ecd8: stub
>   fixme:wincodecs:PngDecoder_Block_GetCount 0x1690b38,0x32f328: stub
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate (System.Uri url) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser:Navigate (System.Uri)
>     at Pokémon3D.Form1.Form1_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0

NeverHood SETUP:

> Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x000d0000 in 32-bit code (0x4239eea6).

...And then a register and stack dump

Neverhood setup95:

> Nothing?!?

Comment: MAC is not an acronym, and therefore not capitalized. It's Mac.

Comment: Good point, I'll fix that.

Comment: some of those steps in the tutorial seemed unnecessary, but if you need ncurses, `sudo port install ncurses` should do the trick. The thing is, it should have been installed as part of the wine install automatically. But that's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: I tried the Wine Bottler combo thing, and it works well for me. Also, it has a nice interface, so I'm going to stick with it. There are some bugs here and there, but it's MUCH easier and more reliable than running through Macports.

Comment: Just wondering, since I think this post is now irrelevant, should I put something in the title? Not "[CLOSED]" but something similar?

Answer (score 3):

Getting ncurses 5.4 is pretty hard.

I wasn't able to find any evidence that that version was available via brew, so had to resort to MacPorts. I referred to their ["Installing older ports"](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort) instructions.

Check the [ncurses Portfile](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/devel/ncurses/Portfile), follow its history backward until you find the version you want.
I searched the history manually on GitHub.
*A more automated search might look something like `git log -S'5.4' -- devel/ncurses/Portfile`… though I didn't have any luck with this myself.*

I found that 5.4 lived at [commit bcc8e4ecb7](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/bcc8e4ecb7b581c246db7c109ab5abe60aa4ba50/devel/ncurses/Portfile). Clone the [macports git repository](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/), and checkout that commit:

```bash
git clone --single-branch https://github.com/macports/macports-ports.git
cd macports-ports
git checkout 686ea4fa0fddeb03fdf2fc04dded68e05181bc95
```

Now go into the ncurses folder and run a port install:

```bash
cd devel/ncurses
sudo port install
```

It attempts to compile. Sadly this is as far as I got. Compiler encounters errors — at least using the toolchain & libraries that I have on macOS Sierra.

Installing this 12-year-old version of ncurses may no longer be  straightforward.

---

**EDIT:** we can compile Apple's distribution of the ncurses source, instead of using the MacPorts project. See [this article](http://www.uponmyshoulder.com/blog/2010/fix-ncurses-in-os-x-10-6-3/).

We want (from [opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com/)) the tarball of [10.6.2](https://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1062.html)'s [`ncurses-27`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-27/). Here's the [`ncurses-27.tar.gz` tarball](http://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/ncurses/ncurses-27.tar.gz).

Build like so:

```bash
make
mkdir -p /tmp/ncurses/Build
sudo make install
```

This should create a file `libncurses.5.4.dylib` at `/private/tmp/ncurses/Release/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib`.

Now we need to install that somewhere. Put it wherever you feel (I dunno, `/usr/local/lib`?) and ensure that the folder in which `libncurses.5.4.dylib` lives, is included in your `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Like, you could add this to your `.profile` (or rather, any file that gets sourced when you run your wine process):

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"
```